# Python fill an array with a specific array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, fill

I am going to fill an array in Python, but I couldn't find a good solution. I am trying to convert a MatLab code like this:

```
data_ax( : , 1:n ) = df( : , 1+n+[1:n] );
```

and `n` could be 1, 2, or 3.

`data_ax` is [200 X 1]

`df` is [200 X 7]

Thank you.

Comment: if data_ax is 200x1 why are you indexing as `data_ax( : , 1:n )` and not simply `data_ax(1:n)`?

Comment: Please make sure this `data_ax( : , 1:n ) = df( : , 1+n+[1:n] )` is correct in MATLAB before trying to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MATLAB code is correct, this is the equivalent Python one using NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

df = np.random.rand(200,7)

n = 2
data_ax = df[:, n+1:2*n+1]
```

Or,

```
data_ax = df[:, 1+n+np.arange(0,n)]
```